# Integration using Cauchy's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am attempting to evaluate the integral $$\int_C\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2n}\frac{dz}{z}$$ where C is the unit circle centered at the origin.

Using parameterized $z=e^{i\theta}$ and got that $$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}\right)\frac{ie^{i\theta}d\theta}{e^{i\theta}} = 2^{2n}i\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos{\theta})^{2n}d\theta$$ I have been looking at applying Cauchy's Theorem and integral formula, but do not see the connection.  Is parameterization the wrong way to approach this?

Comment: What you did, combined with Ron Gordon's answer, gives a very cool proof that $\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos \theta)^{2n}\,d\theta=\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}}\binom{2n}{n}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember, Cauchy's Theorem states that the integral is $i 2 \pi$ times the coefficient of $1/z$ in the integrand.  In this case, you simply want the coefficient of $z^0$ from the binomial piece, which by the binomial theorem is $\binom{2 n}{n}$.  Thus, the integral is $i 2 \pi \binom{2 n}{n}$.

**ADDENDUM**

To see where the binomaial coeeficient comes from, recall that the binomial theorem states that

$$\left( z + \frac1{z} \right ) ^{2 n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2 n} \binom{2 n}{k} z^{2 n-k} \frac1{z^k} = \sum_{k=0}^{2 n} \binom{2 n}{k} z^{2 n-2 k} $$

Note that the coefficient of $z^0$, which occurs when $k=n$, is indeed $\binom{2 n}{n}$.

Comment: I see where you got $i2\pi$ from, but I am having problems getting $\binom{2 n}{n}$ out of $\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2n}$

Comment: @Snagglewhen: see Addendum.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.  But why do we only care about $z^0$?

Comment: @Snagglewhen: as I stated in my answer, Cauchy's theorem states that the integral is $i 2 \pi$ times the coefficient of $1/z$ in the integrand (in this case).  Note that there is a $1/z$ term, so all other factors of $z$ coming from the binomial integrate to zero.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense then.

Answer (score 1):

Write the integral as

$$\int_C \frac{(z^2 + 1)^{2n}}{z^{2n+1}}\, dz$$

and apply Cauchy's differentiation formula to $f(z) = (z^2 + 1)^{2n}$. This results in

$$\frac{2\pi i}{(2n)!} \frac{d^{2n}}{dz^{2n}}\bigg|_{z = 0} (z^2 + 1)^{2n}$$

which is $2\pi i$ times the coefficient of $z^n$ in the expansion of $(z^2 + 1)^{2n}$. So it reduces to $2\pi i \binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: I am looking at Cauchy's differentiation formula, but I don't understand why I should use it if I am trying to integrate.  The formula also uses a point "a" within a closed disk "D".

Comment: @Snagglewhen with that formula, you get $$\frac{2\pi i}{(2n)!}\frac{d^{2n}}{dz^{2n}}\bigg|_{z = 0}(z^2 + 1)^{2n}$$ which can be simplified by noting  it's $2\pi i$ times the coefficient of $z^n$ in the binomial expansion of $(z^2 + 1)^{2n}$.